# How to turn off viewport background

Tags: 3d-view

When I change Viewport Shading to Rendered.
I got this background. How to turn it off?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Make sure "Scene World" is checked in the Viewport Shading options menu.

[image: Scene]

Answer (score 2):

In Render Properties / Film, check "Transparent"